# Any ways to split key and value from a column of a data frame in R, and append the keys as columns name and value for each row of the data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below:

```
source <- data.frame("name" = c('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'),
                 "section" = c('section1', 'section2', 'section3', 'section4'),
                 "values" = c("Type of information:experimental study\nReliability:1 (reliable without restriction)\n\n\nTest guideline, Qualifier:according to\n\n\nGLP compliance:yes\n\n\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:0.01 mg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:0.01 mg/L\n\n\n",
                              "Type of information:experimental study\nReliability:2 (reliable with restrictions)\n\n\nTest guideline, Qualifier:according to\n\nTest guideline, Qualifier:according to\n\n\nGLP compliance:yes\n\n\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:0.002 mg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:0.003 mg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:0.002 mg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:0.005 mg/L\n\n\n",
                              "Type of information:experimental study\nReliability:2 (reliable with restrictions)\n\n\nTest guideline, Qualifier:according to\n\nTest guideline, Qualifier:according to\n\nTest guideline, Qualifier:according to\n\n\nGLP compliance:yes Good laboratory practice compliance statement of July 11, 2014\n\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\nEffect concentrations, Dose descriptor:NOEC\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:9 µg/L\n\n\n",
                              "Type of information:experimental study\nReliability:2 (reliable with restrictions)\n\n\nTest guideline, Qualifier:according to\n\n\nGLP compliance:yes\n\n\nEffect concentrations, Effect conc.:ca. 0.007 mg/L\n\n\n"
                              ))
```

My ideal result is:

```
source_1 <- data.frame("name" = c('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'),
                     "section" = c('section1', 'section2', 'section3', 'section4'),
                     "key1" = c('value1'),
                     "key2" = c('value2'),
                     "key3" = c(NA, NA, 'value3', NA),
                     "key4" = c(NA, 'value4', NA, 'value4'),
                     "key5" = c(NA, NA, 'value5', 'value5'))
```

I was able to get a list of key and a list of value, but don't know how to turn the keys to the column name and assign the value. It will be much appreciated if I can get help from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using `tidyr` library :

We first get the data in long form by splitting on new line character (`'\n'`), get data in two columns splitting on colon (`:`) and finally get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

source %>%
  separate_rows(values, sep = '\n') %>%
  separate(values, c('key', 'value')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value)

#  name  section  key1   key2   key4   key3   key5  
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 name1 section1 value1 value2 NA     NA     NA    
#2 name2 section2 value1 value2 value4 NA     NA    
#3 name3 section3 value1 value2 NA     value3 value5
#4 name4 section4 value1 value2 value4 value3 value5
```

---

Your original dataset requires some data cleaning.

```
source %>%
  separate_rows(values, sep = '\n+') %>%
  filter(values != '') %>%
  separate(values, c('key', 'value'), sep = ':') %>%
  group_by(name, section, key) %>%
  summarise(value = toString(unique(value))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak for your prompt answer. It works perfectly on the pseudo code. However, I got an error and some warnings when I ran them on my real data frame, "Error: Column 3 must be named." I am not sure if it is because there are some same keys with different value, and there are key/value pairs divided by '/n', or '/n/n', or '/n/n/n' in my real data frame.

Comment: Difficult to say without looking at your real data. Is it possible for you to add subset of your real data using `dput` ?

Comment: Thank you Ronak. I have edited my question by adding real data in the Source data frame. I am fairly new to R and this platform. :) I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated answer. There are a lot of new functions for me to study. Excellent!

Comment: What a great experience! I asked the first question and got answered in here! Hooray! Thanks again, @Ronak Shah